# How can I remove an unwanted import alias in Go?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, goimports

I found that very useful Go library in the web https://github.com/deckarep/golang-set that tries to port Python sets to Go.

Thanks to Visual Studio Code I eventually got it to work by importing the library `import "github.com/deckarep/golang-set"` and calling a function in my code:

```
mySet := mapset.NewSet()
```

VS Code automatically recognizes the alias and replaces the import directive:

```
import mapset "github.com/deckarep/golang-set"
```

However, being someone who finds those aliases confusing, I was trying to remove it but doing so, VSCode removes it from both the import statements and my code. VS Code then tells me:

> undeclared name: NewSet compiler(UndeclaredName)

The package name from [NewSet(...)](https://github.com/deckarep/golang-set/blob/main/set.go#L180) is also `package mapset`. So I thought I could simply remove it. But it does not work.

I also tried to work analogously to other 3rd party packages and call the functions by the repository's name:

```
mySet := golang-set.NewSet()
```

This also leads to an error. Is the removing of the alias not possible here due to the hyphen maybe or am I overseeing something else?

Comment: See what your editor is using to format the imports, probably `goimports`. However, as with the formatting of the code itself, it’s usually best to let the formatter decide the style and not worry about it.

Comment: How can I find this out in Vs Code?

Comment: You cannot "get rid" of qualified names unless you want to use a dot import and everybody will sneer at you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several things here:

1. `mapset` is the package name.  You can see this by looking at the [package source code](https://github.com/deckarep/golang-set/blob/main/iterator.go#L26).
2. While the import alias, in this case, is not strictly needed from a language standpoint, it's added for clarity, since the package name (`mapset`) does not match the import path (`golang-set`). Without the alias in the import statement, there's no way to tell how the package is referenced. This is why it's important for it to be there.
3. You cannot use `golang-set` as your import name, becuase the `-` character is not permitted in an import alias. However, if you really want to, you could use `golang_set` or similar, by explicitly providing this as your alias:

   ```golang
   import golang_set "github.com/deckarep/golang-set"
   ```

   Note that this goes against naming conventions, in that packages should not have `_` characters in the name. But it should still be valid.
4. Best practice would be just to use `mapset` as the alias. It's the least confusing of all the available options (which is why it's automatically selected).

Comment: `mapset` itself is also taken on the Github's page, but still I want to get rid of it entirely

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 What do you mean it's "taken"?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/deckarep/golang-set#comprehensive-example :) the packages's author itself uses it like that

Comment: That code example is correct. I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Sure it is. I just want to get rid of the alias as the title of my question states

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am not a "Pro-Go-developer" or something like this. But I got often confused by misleading aliases in Code when I was a beginner. So I habituated myself not to use them and also removing them when refactoring code (as long as it makes sense). This was the first time that I was technically not able to remove it.  (Of course I am aware that on a semantic level `mapset` makes a  lot more sense than `golang-set` or something, but I have to keep my own guidelines.)

Comment: Okay, but that's not a misleading alias. It's the exact opposite. It's added for the express purpose of being NOT misleading.

Comment: You 2. bullet point, however, answers my question now. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. Still I tried to understand why.

Comment: Glad it makes sense now!

Comment: @blackgreen good call. answer updated